# View a localhost:port address over LAN

Tags: port, local-area-network, localhost

I'm working on a Sinatra app so I have a Mongrel instance running at localhost:4567 on my main machine, a Macbook Pro. How can I view the app over my LAN, preferably from an iPhone?

If I enable web sharing I can get to the files in my ~/Sites folder fine but the app doesn't run. If I ammend the :4567 to the IP address Safari can't find the server. If I try just the IP I get the default "It Works!" page. If I add the port then it can't find the server. I'm pretty sure I've set up port forwarding on my router setup page correctly. What am I not doing right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localhost is the loopback address. It's not accessible to anything outside of the computer. You will need to make the Mongrel instance run on an address that is accessible on the LAN.

Comment: ah, i see. i didn't know to try that. thanks!